# How to fill the NaN values with Mode in Python Pandas dataset?

Tags: python, nan, mode

In my data sets (`train`, `test`) `max_floor` values are null for some records. I am trying to fill the null values with the mode of `max_floor` values of apartments which shares the same apartment name:

```
for t in full.apartment_name.unique():
    for df in frames:
        df['max_floor'].fillna((df.loc[df["apartment_name"]==t,   
         'max_floor']).mode, inplace=True)
```

where `full` is `train.append(test)`
and `df` is `[train,test]`

Running the above code is not giving me the expected result. The above code is running fine but is filling all the `max_floor` null values with the below text:

```
bound method Series.mode of 0        NaN
1084     NaN
23278    9.0
Name: max_floor, dtype: float64
```

I just wanted to replace the above text with just the `max_floor` values. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Fix your formatting please.

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: @binilg:You'd get a better answer if you showed the actual code and data you're using. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for some pointers.

Comment: Also, you need to say what value you want to fill with in the case that there are two or more modes. Note that the `Series.mode` method (when called) returns a `Series`, which could contain multiple values (or none).

Comment: how do i add the actual code and data set? as attachment? I can't see an option to add attachment. Sorry for asking too many questions as i am relatively new to this forum.

Answer (score 1):

`mode()` is a function and you've referred to it but not invoked it.

Change `mode` to `mode()`

Comment: using mode() gives error "TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the first value from the `mode()` result. For example:

```
   A    B
0  1  3.0
1  2  NaN
2  2  NaN
3  3  NaN
```

Fill missed values with the mode of the column `A`:

```
df.fillna(df['A'].mode()[0])
```

Output:

```
   A    B
0  1  3.0
1  2  2.0
2  2  2.0
3  3  2.0
```